# Why isn't "carriage return" buffered in Java SE8?

Tags: java

Consider the following code, and let us say that the input character is "Z", which in UNICODE equals to 90.

```
//*********************************
// Read a character from the keyboard.

class KbIn {

  public static void main(String[] args)

   throws java.io.IOException {

     int ch, ch2, ch3;

     System.out.println("Press a key followed by ENTER");

     ch= System.in.read(); // get a character

     ch2= System.in.read(); // get a character

     ch3= System.in.read(); // get a character

     System.out.println(ch);

     System.out.println(ch2);

     System.out.println(ch3);

  }

}
//***************************
```

I would expect that the console output would be:

90 
13
10

This corresponds to Z (90), carriage return (13) and a line feed (10). Instead I get to insert Z twice, and the output is:

90
10
90

So my question is: Does this mean that "carriage return is not buffered"?

I'am using a Terminal on a MacBook (Sierra OS).

Comment: "I would expect [...] carriage return (13)" why?

Comment: If you want to see all the characters in a text file, including the control code sequences that signal the end of a line, you should treat the file as a binary file and read it into a `byte[]` array.  Java's built in text methods will attempt to handle the sequences for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macs only use linefeeds to end lines, not carriage returns. Windows behaves differently, and uses carriage returns.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to java and this issue was killing me.